# Selenium GeckoDriver get IP and Port no of the launched driver instance

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

I'm using Selenium 3.4, Geckodriver 0.17.
I launch FirefoxDriver using the below code

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.bing.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getSessionId());
```

Is there a way I can get the IP and the port of the launched driver instance?

The data I want is printed in the logs.

```
1499170600204   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:38840
1499170601127   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd32 v= and igd10iumd32 v=
1499170608388   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 12793
Jul 04, 2017 5:46:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

The First line of the output **127.0.0.1:38840** prints the info I want. I don't want to parse the log as I will be running drivers in parallel.

Comment: you can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: @Edwin How is that supposed to help me?

Comment: with `getAddress` you can get the ip and check the `getLocalHost`  or `getHostName` for more things

Comment: @Edwin there is no `getAddress` method in the `WebDriver` Object

Comment: in the `InetAddress` - that's why I also gave you the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RemoteWebDriver has [`getCommandExecutor`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getCommandExecutor--) method.

Which can be TypeCasted to `HttpCommandExecutor` and [`getAddressOfRemoteServer()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpCommandExecutor.html#getAddressOfRemoteServer--) method returns the URL.

```
HttpCommandExecutor ce = (HttpCommandExecutor) driver.getCommandExecutor();
System.out.println(ce.getAddressOfRemoteServer());
```