# How to use new geckodriver endpoints?

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

The new geckodriver v0.17.0 has a new way to install addons as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases):

```
POST /session/{session id}/window/fullscreen to invoke the window manager-specific full screen operation
POST /session/{session id}/moz/addon/install to install an extension [Gecko only]
POST /session/{session id}/moz/addon/uninstall to uninstall an extension [Gecko only]
```

How can I use these endpoints to install my addon to firefox for my selenium tests?

Answer (score 4):

You have to know the ip and port in which geckodriver starts. And Once the geckodriver started you can get the Session Id from the driver Instance.

You can get the Ip Address and Port [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907172/3122133)

For ex: if the ip and port is
**localhost:15874**

and session id is **1e53412a-05eb-40a9-8a7b-bb8dd6fd75ab**

Then you can post a json message to

```
http://localhost:15874/session/1e53412a-05eb-40a9-8a7b-bb8dd6fd75ab/moz/addon/install
```

The body of post message should be

```
{
    "path":"xxyy.xpi",
    "temporary":true
}
```

Comment: how can i find which port is geckodriver going to run on?

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody need to use this from .NET client
(as it is not yet implemented)

```
Public Class MyFirefoxDriver
Inherits OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver

Public Sub New(fo As OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions)
    MyBase.New(fo)
    MyBase.CommandExecutor.CommandInfoRepository.TryAddCommand("moz-install-web-ext", New CommandInfo(CommandInfo.PostCommand, "/session/{sessionId}/moz/addon/install"))
End Sub


Public Sub InstallWebExtension(path As String)
    Dim params As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    params.Add("path", path)
    params.Add("temporary", True)
    MyBase.Execute("moz-install-web-ext", params)
End Sub

End Class
```