# Unable to install WebExtension with Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon-webextensions, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to test my firefox webextension but firefox refuses to install it because it doesn't have the `install.rdf` file. But that file is not used anymore by webextensions.

```js
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('geckodriver');

let profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.addExtension(process.cwd() + '/build/firefox/');
profile.setPreference('extensions.firebug.showChromeErrors', true);


let options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);

let _driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('firefox')
.setFirefoxOptions(options)
.build();
```

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/dev/webext/build/firefox/install.rdf'

Is there a setting that I need to enable to tell it it's a webextension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebExtension API is not yet supported by Selenium v3.4.0 . The method `Profile::addExtension` only works for a legacy addon where `install.rdf` is present at the root.

To test a web extension, you can either use a profile where the extension is already installed, or you can implement the custom command available with GeckoDriver since v0.17.0:

```javascript
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var Command = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/command').Command;


function installWebExt(driver, extension) { 
  let cmd = new Command('moz-install-web-ext')
    .setParameter('path', path.resolve(extension))
    .setParameter('temporary', true);

  driver.getExecutor()
    .defineCommand(cmd.getName(), 'POST', '/session/:sessionId/moz/addon/install');

  return driver.schedule(cmd, 'installWebExt(' + extension + ')');
}


var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('firefox')
  .build();

installWebExt(driver, "C:\\temp\\extension.zip");
```

Comment: Thanks! That works!. One question though, is it possible to retrieve the extension internal UUID ? So I could then access the extension's popup

Comment: Check the value returned by `installWebExt`, it could be the UUID: `installWebExt(...).then(id => ...)`

Comment: unfortunately it's the extension's id as it is in the manifest, so it cannot be used for that. But I think I can make some ugly hack to retrieve it from the `about:debugging#addons` page.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with FirefoxDriver. This issue is already logged in both [SeleniumHQ/selenium#4184](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4184) and 
[mozilla/geckodriver#759](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/759)

GeckoDriver [says that](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/759#issuecomment-308522851)

> A workaround for the time being would be to use the add-on endpoints
>   geckodriver 0.17.0 provides to get an extension installed from the
>   local disk.
>
> https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/release/src/marionette.rs#L66

So you have to use the geckodriver endpoints to do that. I have already mentioned on how to use the endpoints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941283/3122133)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't seem that the `getAddressOfRemoteServer ` is available so I'm unable to get the PORT to connect to