# geckodriver won't load extensions with Profile?

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

In either headless and non-headless mode, I'm trying to load a Firefox Dev Edition profile with geckodriver. Firefox opens up fine, and in the extensions list I do see the extensions I use with that profile normally. However, none of the extensions are actually working, and if I go to 'debug extensions' and inspect each one, I see `Error: Protocol Error (unknownError): Extension not found: <extension name>`.

Specifically, I'm using Python with Selenium, with `FirefoxProfile("<profilepath>")`.

Geckodriver.log does show `JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.`, but the profile directory is correct and it is loading (since it shows the proper plugins listed in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you launch FF with existing profile, add-on is shown in about:addons, but nothing works. I think the main reason is that FF makes a copy of the profile in temp windows folder, and some path information is lost somewhere down the way.

So my solution was to load extension as temporary.

[How to use new geckodriver endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935579/how-to-use-new-geckodriver-endpoints/44941283#44941283)

You launch webdriver from derived class and then pass address of your .xpi. No need to search for server address and sessionId, it's magically there.